# sync up progressbar 'fill' with completion messagebox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a *Thread* processing a binary file and storing it in a datatable.
While processing i am updating the progress bar with the current stream position.
My problem is; in the *Thread* I have a finally{} block, and in that I set the progressbar value to the max allowed value, then i run `Application.DoEvents();` then I display a MessageBox, but my MessageBox always appears before the Progressbar fills.

[image: problem]

[here is the applicable code](http://pastebin.com/PMNNR9ce)

[here is a video showing the issue](http://rlemon.com/drop-bin/20111026_1456_58.avi)

I have created a small application to demo the use of a BackgroundWorker instead of a Thread. [Here is the code](http://pastebin.com/GhcjnmFk)

I am seeing the same 'error' ( I am Hesitant to call this an error, more a Usability issue ) As you can see I have also added a *dirty* little logger there. The output *at the end of the log file is:*

> 27/10/2011 4:58:29 PM   -  Progress Entered
>
> 27/10/2011 4:58:29 PM   -  Progress Changed to 79661
>
> 27/10/2011 4:58:29 PM   -  Progress Entered
>
> 27/10/2011 4:58:29 PM   -  Progress Changed to 79661
>
> 27/10/2011 4:58:29 PM   -  Complete Entered
>
> 27/10/2011 4:58:29 PM   -  Events Done
>
> 27/10/2011 4:58:30 PM   -  Message Shown

So there is not a problem with the order in which the commands are being executed... is my only real solution to add a delay before displaying the messagebox?

Comment: Some discussion has been had on the c# chat room. [See Transcript here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1760052#1760052) still no solution, but better knowledge of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try replacing the `Application.DoEvents();` with a simple `Thread.Sleep(100)`. The documentation around `DoEvents` does not seem to indicate whether you are allowed to call it from another, non-UI thread. By using `Thread.Sleep` instead, you're delaying the message box popup and allow the UI thread to process normally.

An alternative method to having the worker background pop up a message box is to use an event, and invoke the subscribed delegates on the UI thread (just like you do for the progress bar).

In fact, if you wanted, you could probably rewrite your thread code to use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) object, and subscribe to the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events. Your actual thread code would be responsible for calling the `ReportProgress` method to fire the `ProgressChanged` event to update your progress bar.

#### Response to update

After looking at your new code, you're never setting the progress bar to the maximum value when your worker completes. In `worker_RunWorkerCompleted` add `progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximum;` before you show the message box. That should update the progress bar to maximum before the message box pops up.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to use a `BackgroundWorker`.  That's the right solution for this problem.

Comment: I preemptively checkmarked this.. the solution (albeit the correct approach) does not solve the problem. I will update my question .

Answer (score 2):

As Joshua suggested, you can't call DoEvents from a different thread than the one your UI is on. Therefore, I would (based on this fact) suggest that you use the `Join()` method on the thread to wait (from the UI thread) until it ends.

You can also invoke a method on the main UI thread from the secondary thread by using a ThreadDispatcher (might be WPF only), or by using the `Invoke()` method on the form.

**Edit**
Another solution would be to make your own form that looks like a MessageBox, and then just make that window show normally, so that it won't block the UI thread.